# ios/iphone photo burst mode api

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to capture multiple photos on highest resolution(AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto) on iPhone 5s. I tried using the following code:

```
    dispatch_semaphore_t sync = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
while( [self isBurstModeEnabled] == YES )
                {
        [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
                             {

                                 if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL)
                                 {
                                     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                                     NSString *videoThumbPath = [NSString
                                                                 stringWithFormat:@"%@/img%d.png",
                                                                 burstFolderPath,
                                                                 index];

                                     [imageData writeToFile:videoThumbPath atomically:YES];
                                     if( 0 == index )
                                     {
                                         [self NSLogPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Created photo at %@",videoThumbPath]];
                                     }
                                 }
                                 dispatch_semaphore_signal(sync);
                             }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sync, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Using this code I can get about 2 photos per second, no way near the performance of burst mode of the native camera app. What am I doing wrong? Also I tried using the code above without the semaphore, but in that case I was having weird behavior, some photos were missing(img0.png img1.png img3.png would be present but img2.png would be missing). Using the second method the performance would be better but still not on par with the native app performance(in my tests the camera app would make about 8.4 photos per second).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:` isn't, I believe, what Apple is using for its burst mode.

Instead, Apple is* *grabbing video frames* at full resolution (which is supported by the 5s). Here's how:

The AVCaptureDevice has its `activeFormat` set to full sensor resolution, then you grab and process 10 frames per second from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`'s `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`, firing off a shutter sound for each frame grab.

You'll need to have a fall-back (either lower-resolution images or a slower burst mode) for devices that don't support video at the full sensor-size resolution—and/or if you want to support anything older than iOS 7.x.

Note that you can't have multiple concurrent usage of `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:` without some extremely unexpected results. This is why you should call each iteration from the previous one's `completionHandler` (which, in essence, is what your semaphore is doing). Also, you may wish to switch from PNG as your file format for burst shots—it saves very slowly and requires a lot of system resource—stacking up 15 or 20 PNGs could cause you some serious grief!

**It's* probably *doing this, because it may, of course, be using a private API to achieve the same end result.*

Comment: I wasn't looking for that precise problem, but I was wondering why some capture formats are 'full-screen', and why some have different ratio (4:3 vs 16:9)... This seems to be related to Image Stabilization, and that explains why `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` doesn't have this problem. (https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/87/why-you-may-want-disable-image-stabilization-during-video-recording). It would seem logical that in burst mode, Image Stabilization isn't used either...

Comment: The only 16:9 formats are those that are HD, which is a 16:9 format by definition. The others are all full-frame, IIRC. `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` can't be used for shooting video, but you *can*, on suitable hardware, shoot video at the same resolution by manually setting the `activeFormat`, not using a preset. With iOS 7.x the presets are very much optional.

Comment: Which is other way of saying the same :) Sensor is 4:3, so any output format that isn't 4:3 actually crops data from sensor. In the case of 16:9 formats, the extra pixels from sensor can be used to do some Image Stabilization, and this feature (`AVCaptureConnection enablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable `) is in fact ONLY available for 16:9 formats. Regarding `activeFormat`, the one you set manually has to be one of `-AVcaptureDevice formats`

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for burst mode in iOS 8 and above:

```
- (void)captureStillImageBracketAsynchronouslyFromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection withSettingsArray:(NSArray *)settings completionHandler:(void (^)(CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer, AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings *stillImageSettings, NSError *error))handler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/index.html)

Comment: This for exposure brackets, not burst capture. See http://www.digital-photo-secrets.com/tip/2111/what-is-exposure-bracketing/ for an intro to exposure bracketing.

Comment: If you don't change the settings then it can use the same setting for each photo and is the recommended way