# AVFoundation - Extract High Resolution Buffer Frames

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, avfoundation, long-integer

AVfoundation offers following method to extract buffer frames:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

However, this provides only low resolution frames (1920 x 1080 at best).

---

```
func capturePhoto(with settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings, delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)
```

Above gives full 12mp (if a late model device), yet it's a one time deal.

---

For a long exposure composite, is there a way to extract full resolution frames within a stream?

Comment: Are you just trying to create a long exposure or are you doing something else with the frames? I think the only way to get the full frame is through AVCapturePhotoOutput

Comment: But that means 'capturing' an image repeatedly, with the shutter sound?

Comment: Err yeah. For a long exposure you can set shutter and iso manually

Comment: I mean for extra long ones, anything over ½ seconds....ike 4 seconds long.

Comment: Just checked and the max exposure time on iPhone7 is 1/3 second, so no good for you sorry

Comment: While checking for something else, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606716/7831758. Could this be of any help

Comment: How would bracketing provide images in a sequence over a time?

Comment: I believe the bracketing code allows you to define the exposures. So you should be able to send the same exposure details multiple times in a row

Comment: Overtime? Intermittently ?

Comment: Sorry the link I sent was related to the deprecated version. Instead of supplying a AVCapturePhotoSettings to capturePhoto() use a AVCapturePhotoBracketSettings. The class contains an array of exposure settings. If you provide multiple versions of the same settings in the array you should get multiple full resolution frames. I haven't tried this personally but this is where I would start looking.

Comment: Understood.  However, I am really confused on one part about Bracketing: How would it be able to deliver frames over a period of time intermittently? Isn't this made to provide bunch of frames with same or different settings AT ONCE? I had the same confusion when it comes to people using bracketing for burst mode.  Feel like I am missing something here....

Comment: In general bracketing is used to create frames with different exposures settings so they can be merged later. The only way to do this though is to take separate frames sequentially. The camera cannot do them all at the same time so it takes each frame separately.